# tableview navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having a issue with trying to get a new viewcontroller to work. I have a `UITableView` that gets loaded from `plist` files. The first row will go to the `detailviewcontroller`, but the next row will not and has a error. The error in the second controller is `DetailViewController2` may not respond to "get steps from file". Any ideas?

```
 DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[detailViewController getStepsFromFile:[files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];

DetailViewController2 *detailViewController2 = [[DetailViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController2" bundle:nil];
[detailViewController2 getStepsFromFile:[files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController2 animated:YES];
[detailViewController2 release];
```

Comment: is it an error or a warning message.

Comment: Where is your getStepsFromFile method declared? Maybe you need a file manager class that gives you the data you need for your tableView. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

i m using this code for the navigation from the tabelview different two screen.

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
        {
            DetailViewController *C = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:C animated:NO];
            [c release];

        }
     else
     {

         DetailViewController1 *C = [[DetailViewController1 alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:C animated:NO];
         [C release];

    }
```

Comment: This works except when I select the second row "DetailViewController2" My app crashes with this in the console                                  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController2 0x732c6c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label

Comment: can you send me u r code in mail i will try for it its working fine in my Application??

Comment: I got it i was way overthinking it, thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the method `-getStepsFromFile` in the .h in order for it to be visible to any instances of the class.

EDIT:
Try it without animation for the first one, then animate the second one like so:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: detailViewController animated: NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: detailViewController2 animated: YES];
```

Comment: I did get rid of that warning but now I crash and in the console I have this:nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-03-09 20:14:45.024 timer[1733:207] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-03-09 20:14:45.025 timer[1733:207] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DetailViewController2: 0x7508f90>.

Comment: You are not allowed to push 2 view controllers onto the stack from the same view, at least with animation.  I recommend pushing only 1, then push the second in -viewdidappear of the first view controller

Comment: I am now getting this error and my app crashes   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController2 0x735e130> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label

Comment: Do you have all the outlets hooked up to the XIB (most importantly the view outlet)?

Comment: Yes all outlets are hooked up. Works fine until i add the DetaiViewController2 to the code

Comment: Before I go, let me just say that you must have an unset key for the view outlet.  Google your error before you comment, as not every answer provider knows how to fix very problem, plus it brings up 250 million google results.